# Import excel data in Kendo UI Grid in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, import-from-excel

I am using Kendo UI grid in ASP MVC and in need to import excel data in the grid. Does anyone know if that is even possible? Looked online but couldn't find any samples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kendo doesnt support it. but you can do it with your own way all you have upload your worksheet server, analysis worksheet then call analysed data to  view back  , then just push data to grid.datasource via javascript

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-push

Answer (score 0):

It's not a supported feature yet, there's a closer solution which worked for me as an alternative,

The [Copy from excel to grid](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/copy-from-excel-to-grid), and it could be built using just the front-end side.